# Substituir letra pela posição

Tags: python, string

Eu estou fazendo um simples jogo da forca em python e gostaria de saber se tem como fazer um replace pela posição da letra.

Tipo quero que na posiçao 1 o '*' seja substítuido pela letra que desejo.

**Código:**

```
palavra_secreta = 'alura'
enforcou = False
acertou = False
secret = '*' * len(palavra_secreta)

while not enforcou and not acertou:

    print(f'{secret}\n\n'.center(28))

    chute = str(input('Qual letra? '))
    chute = chute.strip()

    if chute in palavra_secreta:
        for i in range(0, len(palavra_secreta)):
            if chute.lower() == palavra_secreta[i].lower():
               secret = secret.replace(secret[i], chute)
    else:
        print(f'A letra {chute} não contem na palavra.')

    time.sleep(3)

    os.system('clear')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String no Python é imutável, mas você poderia substituir, por exemplo, o caractere da posição 5 de uma string da seguinte forma:

```
s = s[0:5] + c + s[6:]
```

Se fosse caso de precisar de performance, é melhor usar uma lista de caracteres (mutável) em vez de string, mas para um caso simples assim, a solução acima basta.

Comment: Bom algoritimo meu amigo...Muito obrigado.Mais  como voçe disse a soluçao com listas fica melhor.Consegui fazer com lista.Vlws

Comment: É, fica mais limpo mesmo.